# Convert a cell array of cells to cell arrays of doubles

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

Let's say, that i have a cell array of cells containing only numeric values. Its name is Q.

```
Q = { {[0]    [1]    [0]    [238]} }
Q{1}

ans = 

    [0]    [1]    [0]    [238]
```

What i would like to do, is to combine all these 4 cells into just one.
In that case, it would be something like the one below:

```
Q{1}

ans =

     0     1     0   238
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double-nested cell array:

```
Q = { {[0]    [1]    [0]    [238]} }
```

and you need [**comma-separated lists**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) to transform it into an array. I assume you have multiple cell arrays within `Q`, so you can use `cellfun`:

```
out = cellfun(@(x) [x{:}], Q,'uni',0)
```

and you get

```
Q{1} = 

    [0]    [1]    [0]    [238]


out{1} =

     0     1     0   238
```

For one element this is equivalent to:

```
Q{1} = [Q{1}{:}]
```

as the `x` in the `cellfun` operation is equivalent to `Q{i}` where `i` is the running variable.

But if you you just have this one array in your cell array, consider:

```
out = cell2mat(Q{:})
```

as you don't need it to be a cell array at all.

Comment: `Q{1} = cell2mat(Q{1})` ?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks a lot, Q{1} = [Q{1}{:}] worked just fine. That's what i really needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
Q{1} = [Q{1}{:}]
```

Comment: Good afternoon!  I've made a MATLAB chat room for us so we can discuss anything and everything related to MATLAB... things that may be off-topic as a question, or stuff that can't fit into the span of a comment.  Visit us when you have the time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab